# How does my useContext component know to get the value in App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, use-context

I'm following a tutorial and it looks like this:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Index } from './pages/index';
import { About } from './pages/about/about';
import { UserContext } from './UserContext';

function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to='/'> Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <UserContext.Provider value='hello from context'>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Index} />
      <Route path='/about/' component={About} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AppRouter;
```

UserContext.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react'



export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

index.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';

export function Index() {
  const msg= useContext(UserContext);



  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>;
      <div>{msg}</div>;
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I run this react app, {msg} becomes the `hello from context` from the `App.js` file.

What I don't get is when I look at `index.js` it is importing from the `UserContext.js` only, how does it know that the `value` is in `App.js` file?  In my mind it would only see that if I also imported the `App.js` file.  But the react app just knows where to find it.  Is the answer that when `index.js` imports `UserContext` the app looks all over to see where else `UserContext.js` was imported from and then builds the output of the react app from everything that it sees? I feel like I'm missing a big part of react apps that would make everything more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without lifting the veil that is the React framework, ReactDOM, and Fiber, it may be easiest to think of the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) as an **optimized version** of the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern.

It's not that React is crawling all your imports and such to determine which files are used, but rather, it's the DOM (React's VirtualDOM) that is generated when you compose all your components to form your app. You use JSX to describe the UI structure.

We'll start by using a lifting state up example.

```
const Child1 = ({ value }) => <div>{value}</div>;

const Child2 = ({ setValue }) => <button onClick={() => setValue(42)}>Update</button>;

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Child1 value={value} />
      <Child2 setValue={setValue} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Here we've a Tree with `Parent` as the root and two leaf nodes, `Child1` and `Child2`. Note that `Child1` doesn't know, or care, about where `value` comes from or how it's updated, it just receives a prop. Similarly, `Child2` doesn't know, or care, about what is consuming the value it's updating.

We'll lift state up a level and add an intermediate component.

```
const IntermediateComponent1 = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>I'm an intermediate child component</h1>
    <Child1 value={props.value} />
  </div>
);

const IntermediateComponent2 = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>I'm another intermediate child component</h1>
    <Child2 setValue={props.setValue} />
  </div>
);

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <IntermediateComponent1 value={value} />
      <IntermediateComponent2 setValue={setValue} />
    </>
  );
};
```

You should now notice two things:

1. Child 1 and 2 are further apart, but the general DOM structure allows data to flow from a single location and be consumed by children further down the tree.
2. Intermediate components need to be aware of props they need to proxy on to their descendants (an issue/pattern known as "props-drilling").

The React Context API is a way to do the same thing but not need to explicitly pass (*drill*) props down through all intermediate children. The context provider is the root node providing a value to be consumed by children further down the tree.

```
const Child1 = () => {
  const { value } = useContext(MyContext); // <-- "value" out
  return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const Child2 = () => {
  const { setValue } = useContext(MyContext); // <-- "setValue" out
  return <button onClick={() => setValue(42)}>Update</button>
};

const IntermediateComponent1 = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>I'm an intermediate child component</h1>
    <Child1 />
  </div>
);

const IntermediateComponent2 = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>I'm another intermediate child component</h1>
    <Child2 />
  </div>
);

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}> // <-- "value" in
      <IntermediateComponent1 />
      <IntermediateComponent2 />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now hopefully you can see how values being provided from a context can be consumed by descendants via the generated DOM Tree structure. When consuming a context, children will access the context value of the closest Context Provider ***above*** them in the Tree. In other words, the closest ancestor Provider component.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get the first code block working, is that basically pseudocode, like I should set up a hook to define setValue?  https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @filifunk It's not pseudocode, though I didn't explicitly go into the details of declaring the context, I assumed you knew how to do this already and were just asking how the consuming components "know" which context to consume from. Your codesandbox doesn't appear to have any code in it beyond the initial template code, did you save your changes?

Comment: @filifunk Please check this running codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-does-my-usecontext-component-know-to-get-the-value-in-app-js-pd7e3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, thank you!  Really dumb separate question but after the first code block on your first answer you say that "it just receives a prop"...that was confusing to me I think because I always thought receiving a prop means explicitly saying "prop" in the code.  I tried to look at tutorials on props and I still feel that way.  I'm sure I have it all wrong, but Is `const child1 = ({ value }) => <div>{value}</div>` still considered receiving a prop?

Comment: @filifunk All React components are passed a `props` object, whether you refer to it or not depends on if any props are passed and need to be accessed in children components. You can also either call the `props` object "props" (*you can name it whatever you like, but "props" is convention*) `const child1 = props => {....` and use `props.propValue` or you can use destructuring assignment `const child1 = ({ propValue }) => {....` and access the `propValue` prop. When I was referring to "receives a prop" I wanted the focus to be on the fact we were explicitly passing props.

Comment: @filifunk This was to build up showing how you have a source of true in the React tree and why/how passing props can become problematic when you need to start props drilling between source and consuming components. With the Context API you no longer need to pass props.